# Do i still need to cancel my existing visa which is expiring before my flight?

Tags: schengen-visas, repeat-visits

I have an existing Schengen visa given by Netherlands and expires on April 27, 2019. I am applying again for a visa going to france, my flight schedule is on April 29-may 6 2019. Do I still need to process the cancellation of my existing visa where in fact it is expiring before my flight. Some said existing visa should be cancelled before you can apply for new visa.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to ask to have the old visa canceled in this situation.

What you've heard is probably a garbled version of the fact that Schengen consulates normally do not issue *overlapping* short-stay visas -- which in some retellings can become something like "one cannot have two visas in the same passport at the same time". However, this is not a rule that is actually observed.