# Multiple Entry Visa Cancellation and Applying New Visa

Tags: schengen-visas, business-travel, repeat-visits

I have a multiple entry Schengen visa that is valid till June 8, 2019 from Dutch Embassy and I have to travel to Italy on June 9, 2019. Do I need to cancel my Schengen visa before applying for new visa?

Comment: Thanks! however, Is there any policy for this where I can refer!

Comment: I've nominated this question for reopening.  The other question is certainly very similar and was posted first, it is true, but because LOL4673 specifically requested an official source and reported conflicting information from the third-party service provider, this answer is more comprehensive. It would also be nice for LOL4673 to be able to post his or her own answer explaining what was needed to get the service provider to change its tune.

Comment: I shall update once I actually submit visa application at VFS which is scheduled for April 9, 2019. But I just email embassy explaining about my situation and they said I can apply...

Comment: I applied on April 17, 2019 and I got my Schengen Visa on April 30, 2019 and it is a overlapping visa and they sent me a letter where they have asked me to use correct visa while entry and exit.  I was not asked to cancel any visa, although VFS wont accept until you have email from Embassy / Consulate General

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to cancel your visa.

The [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), Article 9(1), explicitly contemplates applications for multiple-entry visas during the validity of another multiple-entry visa, as long as the validity of the first visa is at least six months:

> CHAPTER II
>
> Application
>
> Article 9
>
> Practical modalities for lodging an application
>
> 1. Applications shall be lodged no more than three months before the start of the intended visit. Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa valid for a period of at least six months.

This is also reflected in the [Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the
modification of issued visas](https://www.udiregelverk.no/PageFiles/2788/Visa_Handbook_I_09.07.2014.pdf), in Part II ("Operational Instructions on the Processing of Visa
Applications"), section 3.1 (the last example and the preceding paragraph are relevant to your case):

> 3. LODGING OF AN APPLICATION
>
>    3.1. When can an application be lodged?
>      Legal basis: Visa Code, Article 9(1)
>
>    A visa application should in principle be lodged at least 15 calendar days before the intended visit (as this is the normal processing time) and cannot be lodged earlier than three months before the start of the intended visit. It is the applicant's responsibility to take the necessary precautions to respect the deadlines where an appointment system is in place. However, applicants should be informed of the various deadlines, see the Handbook for the organisation of visa sections and local Schengen cooperation, Part I, point 4.
>
>    An application lodged less than 15 calendar days before the intended departure may be accepted, but the applicant should be informed that the processing time may be of up to 15 calendar days. If, nevertheless the applicant insists on lodging the application he should be informed that the final decision might be taken after the intended date of departure
>
>    > Example: A Turkish national decides to book a special last minute offer for a skiing vacation in Austria with a departure within two days and only the day before departure he realises that he needs a visa to enter Austria.
>    >
>    > In this case the Austrian consulate could refuse to deal with the application.
>
>    A holder of a multiple-entry visa may apply for a new visa before the expiry of the validity of the visa currently held. However, the validity of the new visa must complement the current visa, i.e. a person cannot hold two uniform visas valid for the same period in time.
>
>    > Example: A Moroccan lawyer representing a gender equality NGO who frequently participates in meetings in various Member States holds a multiple-entry-visa which expires on 31.5. She applies for a new visa on 15.4.
>    >
>    > If a new visa is issued, it should be valid from 1.6. and in such a case the visa holder would be entitled to enter the territory of the Member States on the basis of the first visa that will expire during the stay and leave on the basis of the new visa.

The last example clearly shows that you should be able to submit an application for a multiple-entry visa during the validity period of another multiple-entry visa.  If the second visa is issued, its validity must begin no earlier than the day after the expiration of the first visa.  So the Italian consulate (and its third-party visa service provider) should indeed process your application for a visa beginning on June 9th.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had Multi Entry visa from June 8, 2018 to June 8, 2019. I am Indian National btw! I traveled only once to Netherlands, Denmark and Sweden and the travel was completed in 3 week and afterwards there was no entry. Hence it was just used once....even though it was MEV. I hope this wont be an issue as they might think I requested for Multi Entry and traveled only once that too in June 2018 only..

Comment: Hmm, that is a curious wording in the Visa Code. It appears to presuppose that holders of shorter visas _cannot_ lodge a new application before the old visa expires. But such a rule (which would invalidate my answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134469/do-i-still-need-to-cancel-my-existing-visa-which-is-expiring-before-my-flight)) doesn't seem to be defined explicitly anywhere.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I agree.  The visa code wording is unfortunate and seems to imply a limit on holders of single-entry visas and shorter-term multiple entry visas that seems frankly unreasonable and is possibly unintended.  Furthermore, because the limitation is implicit, it is ambiguous.  For longer-term multiple-entry visas, though, as in this case, the situation is not ambiguous.

Comment: @LOL4673 Multiple entry visas in general cover the *possibility* of more trips.  Even if you had a concrete plan for a second trip, you should not be penalized if your plans changed for any legitimate reason.  Legitimate reasons for cancellation of a trip can be fairly trivial, for example, if someone is thinking of a vacation in one country and decides instead to go to another country, or decides that the time off from work would be better spent at home cleaning the basement, or, for that matter, sitting around doing nothing.

Comment: Thanks...I'll apply by 1st week of April 2019. Some of my colleagues told me that they cancel my existing visa even if I ask them to give me new visa from June 9, 2019. I have to travel to Paris in end of May 2019 and then I have travel coming on June 9, 2019. I'll mention this in my cover letter. Hopefully they will understand. I travel frequently to US, UK and Canada, but, Schengen visa is the most complicated and most paper / labor intensive work and travel desk in my company / VFS India doesn't help either...Anyhow thanks for all your responses!

Comment: Its weird VFS Italy in India is saying that I need to cancel my existing visa before applying for new one!

Comment: @LOL4673 maybe you should draw their attention to Article 9(1) and to the handbook (see edited answer) and ask them to confirm with the consulate. I think VFS often oversimplifies their instructions or perhaps receives oversimplified instructions. If VFS won't listen to you, try to raise a formal complaint through their procedures (e.g., http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/delhi/customer_experience.html, and to escalate, https://www.vfsglobalcustomerexperience.com/CMS/Complaint/Escalate). If that fails, try to get in touch directly with the consulate/embassy or the ministry of foreign affairs.

Comment: I have explained my situation in an email to Embassy of Italy and I received reply that I can apply for visa. Thanks. Lets see I have booked appointment. Dear Applicant,

 

You may apply for a visa valid from 09/06/2019

 

Thank you with best regards


Embassy of Italy

New Delhi

Comment: @LOL4673 thank you for reporting this. I have nominated the question to be reopened in the hope that you can post an answer describing your experience in more detail.